# MS CRM: Allow to Create entity record only from subgrid

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, customization, dynamics-crm-2016

I am using MS CRM 2016 On-Premises.
I am configuring child entity and parent entity.
I need to allow child entity creation only from subgrid on parent entity.
And to disable child entity creation from other child entity views and forms and from advanced find.

If I will use Create privileges restriction - won't it allow me to create child entity record from subgrid?
Are there any ways to realize it?

Thank you.
With regards, Yuriy.

Answer (score 0):

If problem is only in UI you could make 'parentId' field in form as read-only, and check if it's filled. As far as I know it's automatically filled when record is created from subgrid.